# Trouble creating system account and running a cron job under it

Tags: cron, adduser

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server installed on a raspberry pi 4 (no desktop) and I am trying to create a system account and have a script run under the system account when the system boots (the solution I found was to make a cron job).

The reason I want to do this is because my pi is headless, so I ssh into it, and found that when I disconnect my session that the application I start closes (since the shell closes when the session closes). It would also be nice to be able to run other commands when the app is up without having to start a new session.

This is what I have done so far: Tried to create system account

```
adduser --system --no-create-home --shell /bin/false --ingroup root --disabled-password --disabled-login <account name>
```

Tried to setup a cron job

```
crontab -e
```

Added the line below into crontab

```
@reboot <account name> sleep 30 && /directory/script.sh &
```

of course I have the actual account name sub'ed w/o the <>. Also directory is sub'ed for the full directory.

I think at least part of the problem has to do with the user account. I verified it exists and has the correct membership, but if I try to su to it, I get an error that the user doesn't exist.

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: I think you will find you don’t need any other account. The root user or your own user should work fine. Using your own user will not prevent you connecting using ssh. Having sent that I don’t think cron is the best tool for the job. You can add create a service unit with a few lines of configuration and start it with systemd. With raspbian there is also a rc.local file which you can use. Not sure if that exists in Ubuntu server for the pi but you can certainly enable it.

Comment: Thanks, this rout is what I actually ended up doing, and it works